# jQuery:Parsing an ajax HTML page result with jQuery

Tags: jquery

It seems that there are already a lot of SO entries exist about that, but I cant find a Silver Bullet to solve my problem.

Basically I just want an Ajax way to show google search results on my page, so I made a sample page with code like following:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Baidu</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var obj = 
        $.ajax({
            url:"https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow"
        });
    alert(obj);
});
</script>
<body>
</body>  
</html>
```

After that I got a `[object object]`.So my question is :

1. What did I get and how to parse it?
2. In my condition,which parameters should I set with to the method [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Comment: cross domin issue .. use jsonp... and use `console.log(obj)` to view the object in you dveveloper tools console and  not `alert`

Comment: That's not possible, doesn't matter what you do, Google uses frame blocking and inserts all the content you see on your screen with javascript, so you simpy can not scrape Google that way, and certainly not with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can't make an ajax call to Google because their domain is different to that of your code.

Suggested solution is to proxy the request through a server side script that resides on the same domain, and either make a HTTP request to get the search results or use the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you cannot use ajax call to another domain

To retrieve google search results programmatically you may try using their [custom search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Google has made API to make custom search ans design. This is the [link](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/)

To view the `[object object]` Content juste use this fonction :

```
alert(print_r(obj,true));

function print_r (array, return_val) {
  var output = '',
    pad_char = ' ',
    pad_val = 4,
    d = this.window.document,
    getFuncName = function (fn) {
      var name = (/\W*function\s+([\w\$]+)\s*\(/).exec(fn);
      if (!name) {
        return '(Anonymous)';
      }
      return name[1];
    },
    repeat_char = function (len, pad_char) {
      var str = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        str += pad_char;
      }
      return str;
    },
    formatArray = function (obj, cur_depth, pad_val, pad_char) {
      if (cur_depth > 0) {
        cur_depth++;
      }

      var base_pad = repeat_char(pad_val * cur_depth, pad_char);
      var thick_pad = repeat_char(pad_val * (cur_depth + 1), pad_char);
      var str = '';

      if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && obj.constructor && getFuncName(obj.constructor) !== 'PHPJS_Resource') {
        str += 'Array\n' + base_pad + '(\n';
        for (var key in obj) {
          if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === '[object Array]') {
            str += thick_pad + '[' + key + '] => ' + formatArray(obj[key], cur_depth + 1, pad_val, pad_char);
          }
          else {
            str += thick_pad + '[' + key + '] => ' + obj[key] + '\n';
          }
        }
        str += base_pad + ')\n';
      }
      else if (obj === null || obj === undefined) {
        str = '';
      }
      else {
        str = obj.toString();
      }

      return str;
    };

  output = formatArray(array, 0, pad_val, pad_char);

  if (return_val !== true) {
    if (d.body) {
      this.echo(output);
    }
    else {
      try {
        d = XULDocument; 
        this.echo('<pre xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="white-space:pre;">' + output + '</pre>');
      } catch (e) {
        this.echo(output);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  return output;
```